# How can I prevent the default academic theme from overriding the dark theme on my Hugo site?

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I've made this Hugo [site](https://peerchristensen.netlify.com) using the blogdown R package. The theme is the dark version of the "academic" theme.

Somehow I can't publish new posts without weird changes to the theme on the main page. 
As you can see from the image, the nav-bar, text and icons (but not the main background) look as if the default theme overrides parts of the dark theme:

[image: screenshot]

This is also the case when I use serve_site() locally.
I noticed that when I render the site, the proper "dark" settings appear for half a second, but then these weird changes appear to override them.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the theme, or blogdown.